# Can we remove secure login option alone from Magento

Tags: magento, https, magento-1.4

Is there way to disable the secure login/registeration/forgot password alone, but all other pages like checkout customer dashboard area can use https but i want to disable secure url for only customer login/registeration/forgot pages, i checked on custome r module /etc/config.xml but couldnot find anything like that.

Please help me

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you'll want to do all this from app/code/local/ of course!

With that being said you'll need to extend/edit app/code/core/Mage/Customer/etc/config.xml:

```
    <secure_url>
        <customer>/customer/account/</customer>
    </secure_url>
```

...and remove it.

Next you'll need to edit/extend app/code/Core/Mage/Customer/Helper/Data.php:

and modify the _getUrl()'s to force using secure url on the pages you want it to be secure:

```
return $this->_getUrl('customer/account', array('_secure' => true));
```

NOTE: Like everyone else mentioned this isn't exactly a good idea from a security stand point.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I did the above two changes first time, and cleared cache, but never able to see login page in http after enabled secure url for front end. using mage 1.4.2

Comment: Make sure you're updating the other return _getUrl's in the Data.php helper.  Not just the one I listed.

Answer (score 3):

Did you think that Login pages are accessed via HTTPS for a reason? The reason is to protect them from modification. Removing HTTPS will open a huge security hole and will cause leakage of passwords of your web site visitors.

Comment: Even if i am going to use ajax based login? The problem is am loading login page in home page using fancybox. So its become mixed content problem because browser deals it like http and https, thats why i wanted remove https for these.

Comment: I just wanted to know how can i remove https from login url alone.

Comment: @Ela I am not aware of details, but as I said, removal of HTTPS from login page will open a security hole. Period.

Answer (score 1):

So, you should overload the blocks that contents url links and rework it to get urls witout http. But the good is to use in your box the iframes.

Comment: It's not obvious but Ela is deliberately avoiding iframes as stated in his [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4859735/471559).

Comment: Yes you are right, placed it in iframe . by passing 'type'   :    'iframe', for fancybox. But again this IE8 denied page because it tells am loading https over http page in iframe